# How do you branch by TFS Collection

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Thanks for your help in advance.

I was wondering if it was possible to branch by collection in TFS2010?

Basically, I have a collection called "ReleaseTesting", and when I right click on it I am able to see the menu for "Branching and Merging", however it is greyed out.

So, is it possible to branch by collection? Just by the fact that the menu is there, leads me to believe that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean branch from one collection to another then no it's not possible (or branch from the root of a collection to create another). Behind the scenes collections in TFS are seperate databases and cannot share any artefacts (code, work items, builds etc).

If you need to move code between collections and maintain history the you could use the [TFS integration platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you are on the right track.  Remember that TFS has it's own permissions.  So if something is greyed out, it could be because you don't have permissions.

For example, the new folder icon for me is greyed out sometimes, depending where in the folder tree I am.

Standard answer- contact you administration, i know that is not very helpful though.